# Append ID to some element from other element click action

Tags: jquery, click, appendto

i have a little problem with jQuery. I want to append ID for element from other element after that i click on it... :) So, if i click some list element this element id will go to another, can you hel me? This is my code...

```
        $('#main_menu li').click(function(){
            (this.id).appendTo('.main_content ul')
        })
```

Comment: `appendTo` is for inserting DOM elements: http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/ and is a method of jQuery objects, not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#main_menu li').click(function(){
  $('.main_content ul').attr('id', this.id);
});
```

Here `this.id` will get the clicked element `id` and set that `id` to `.main_content ul`.

#### But this will make `id` duplication, which is not allowed.

Instead of `id` you can make `class`:

```
$('#main_menu li').click(function(){
  $('.main_content ul').attr('class', this.id);
});
```

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski but don't make **id duplicaton**.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the element itself:

```
$('#main_menu li').click(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('.main_content ul')
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/AbeyT/